# How to set root url in django urls.py ? Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, web

I have just started with django now and was configuring urls. I am able to map different urls like /posts, /posts/create etc. Somehow I am not able to configure root url, I am not sure what wrong I am doing. Here is my configuration :

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$',homeViews.posts),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^posts/',homeViews.posts),
url(r'^createPost/',homeViews.createPost),
```

Here is the **View** Code

```
def posts(request):
  t = get_template('index.html')
  postList = Post.objects()
  html = t.render(Context({'posts':postList}))
  return HttpResponse(html)
```

Strange thing is, when I set DEBUG=True in settings, root url '^$' works but not with DEBUG=False (400 Bad Request). Not sure what is wrong.
Please help me out .

Edit :

Here is the complete urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rrdquest import views as homeViews
from manage.user import views as userViews


urlpatterns = [
# Examples:
url(r'',homeViews.posts),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^posts/',homeViews.posts),
url(r'^createPost/',homeViews.createPost),
url(r'^createUser/',userViews.createUser),
url(r'^post/(?P<title>[a-z,A-Z]+)/$',homeViews.post),
]
```

Cheers!

Comment: Please post your complete `urls.py`.

Comment: What's the error in your console?

Comment: I have updated my question with complete url configurations. When DEBUG=False, console gives [05/May/2015 17:49:42]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 26

Comment: What about ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py ?

Comment: You got it Adem! ALLOWED_HOSTS had 127.0.0.1 and running it with 127.0.0.1:8000 worked, though css did not apply but view worked. Thanks a lot. How do I close the question to accept your answer as it is in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALLOWED_HOSTS` is a required part of setup,

So should set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` like this, in `settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

or like this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```